# check if a value exists before updating database Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a query to add isbn to table...It is working fine but if I try to insert an isbn that already exists it gives me an error. How do I check if a value exist?

Here is my query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cart (isbn, hardcover_purchased, softcover_purchased, ebook_purchased)
          VALUES ('0061348112', 1, 0, 0)";
```

Comment: get's asked once a day at least. Please search of INSERT IGNORE, REPLACE, or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over again. Read the manuals and understand how everything works.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the update like this:

```
UPDATE Tokens
SET refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'
WHERE id = '2'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT refresh_token FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token ='C08Rbs')
```

Use  ROW_COUNT() to determine if any rows were actually updated. Assuming the row where id = 2 actually exists, it will return 0 if no rows were updated (because the value already exists).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. For example:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO cart (isbn, hardcover_purchased, softcover_purchased, ebook_purchased) VALUES ('0061348112', 1, 0, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE isbn=isbn;';
```